# Wordpress manipulate comment_reply_link() add #nav-comform to the link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a theme for a friend but get stuck ...
The comments and the comment form are inside a jquery tab.
To toggle the tab on a klick of the reply link i have to add #nav-comform to the link.

Example:

```
http://localhost/?p=109&replytocom=10#respond#nav-comform
```

I know i have to work with a filter in the functions.php but i have never done it before so i am a little lost and everything i try fail ...

I know it should be something like this filter example to add rel="nofollow" to the reply link:

```
function add_nofollow_to_reply_link( $link ) {
return str_replace( '")\'>', '")\' rel=\'nofollow\'>', $link );
}

add_filter( 'comment_reply_link', 'add_nofollow_to_reply_link' );
```

Maybe some one can lead me a way ?

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
function add_link_hash($args){
    $args['respond_id'] = 'nav-comform';
    return $args;
}
add_filter('comment_reply_link_args', 'add_link_hash', 10);
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! You saved me hours ... I dont get there is a comment_reply_link_args hook to manipulate the $args array ...